# Link Aggregation (Etherchannel) between 2 cisco switches ( fibre link, and with an intermediate switch)

Tags: cisco, switch, etherchannel

I have 3 switches soon to be setup in topology as shown below [image: switches]

I have a fibre link and LAN cable directly connecting switch1 and switch3 and also another connection going from switch1 to switch3 via switch2 using LAN cables.

I want to have Link Aggregation Group(LAG) at switch1 for the 3 ports (2 directly connecting to switch3 and one through intermediate switch2) for getting higher bandwidth and failover redundancy for switch3.

Q1- Is it possible to have LAG with the indirect connection through switch2 as shown in the figure?

Q2- How would I configure LAG for ports @ switch1? (If you point me to exact commands or any resources links, it would be helpful)

Q3- Do I need to configure LAG @ switch3 also for corresponding ports?

Q4- What modes(active/passive/on) should I use for LACP @ switch1 and @switch3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: This requires MLAG (multichassis LACP) to work. You can't split and splice a simple static or LACP trunk.

Q2: As far as I know, SG500X and SG300 don't support MLAG. You can configure a LAG trunk for the two lines between S1 and S3 though and use STP(Spanning Tree Protocol) to take care of the looping links to S2.

Q3: LAG trunks need to be configured on both terminating switches.

Q4: Use LACP whenever possible; static trunking should only be used when LACP isn't possible.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. LACP has 2 modes right? `active` and `passive`. What modes should I use at S1 and S3? if I'm not mistaken one should be `active` and one should be `passive` or both should be `active`. Does it matter which of these switches is configured for `active` or `passive` LACP?

Comment: At least one side requires active negotiation. With both sides on passive, the trunk won't come up. I use active on both sides.

Comment: need clarification, in Q2 by ` two lines`  you mean 1 fibre and 1 ether?

Comment: @jaggi Yes - the PHY doesn't matter. LAG links are required to use the same speed though.

Comment: Cisco SG500X-24 has 1Gbps ethernet port and 10Gbps fibre port. What needs to be done in this case?

Comment: You can't aggregate different speeds. You can use the 10G link while the 1G link S1-S3 is usually blocked by spanning tree with another redundant, blocked path across S2 (blocked between S1 and S2, assuming the root bridge is located in the main network).